# Regex find sting in the middle of two strings

Tags: regex

I want to get the time in the following line. I want to get the string

```
2017-07-07 08:30:00.065156
```

in

```
[ID] = 0,[Time] =  2017-07-07 08:30:00.065156,[access]
```

I tried this

```
 (?<=[Time] = )(.*?)(?=,)
```

Where i want to get the string in-between the time tag and the first comma but this doesn't work.

Comment: What regex flavour is it? Maybe it doesn't support lookarounds. Can you retrieve the content from specific capturing groups?

Comment: Escape the `[`: `(?<=\[Time] = )(.*?)(?=,)`

Comment: Yes, what programming language are you using? Add it's tag to your post.

Comment: `(?<=\[Time] = )([^,]+)` should also work and will be more efficient.

Comment: There's also two spaces after the `=`.  It shouldn't cause your regex to fail, but you may have to trim the regex results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Time]` inside a regex means a `T`, an `i`, an `m`, or an `e`, unless you escape your square brackets.

You can drop the reluctant quantifier if you use `[^,]*` in place of `.*`:

```
(?<=\[Time\] = )([^,]*)(?=,)
```